# how to save the state of radio buttons

Tags: android

I have made 4 radio buttons and want to save the state when any of them is clicked and then want to use that saved state in the application.How can i do that?

```
                    myOption1.setChecked(true);
        myOption2.setChecked(true);
        myOption3.setChecked(true);
        myOption4.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Be more specific, do you want to save your UI state or save your state to be persistent.

Comment: Yup. @biegleux solves the first part (UI) and my solution is better suited for the latter one, so you'll have to make your pick. :)

Comment: actually the problem is that the last radion button is unclickable initially untill you click some other button.After clicking some other radio button,the last radio button becomes clickable.plz tell me how to solve this problem sir

Comment: If you find solution here. Kindly accept the correect answer by click "Tickmark" at left side.

Answer (score 5):

Override [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption1", myOption1.isChecked());
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption2", myOption2.isChecked());
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption3", myOption3.isChecked());
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("myOption4", myOption4.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  myOption1.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption1"));
  myOption2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption2"));
  myOption3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption3"));
  myOption4.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("myOption4"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're only going to have 4 radio buttons all in all, you might as well store their "values" in `SharedPreferences` (persistant storage).

Example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor shEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();

shEditor.putBoolean("checkbox_1", myOptionOne.isChecked());
shEditor.putBoolean("checkbox_2", myOptionTwo.isChecked());
shEditor.putBoolean("checkbox_3", myOptionThree.isChecked());
shEditor.putBoolean("checkbox_4", myOptionFour.isChecked());

shEditor.commit();
```

Use it by doing the following:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

 myOptionOne.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_1", false));
 myOptionTwo.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_2", false));
 myOptionThree.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_3", false));
 myOptionFour.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkbox_4", false));
```

Comment: and how to use it somewhere else in the activity sir

Comment: If you like my answer, don't forget to upvote/accept it to the left so that other people will know that it's what you've picked!

Answer (score 0):

Save that value in sharedPreferences Concept. Sample Example has been placed here that uses predefined method called addPreferencesFromResource() that will get the state of checkbox value  automatically and saved in the preferences.

```
    public class EditPreference extends PreferenceActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.checkboxpref);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.checkboxpref);
        }
    }
```

And layout Code should be this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:key="@string/checkbox_pref"

    android:title="@string/eidt_preferences">

<CheckBoxPreference

    android:key="@string/pref_12_time_format"

    android:title="@string/time_formats"

    android:summary="@string/twelve_hour" 

    android:defaultValue="true"/>

<CheckBoxPreference

    android:key="@string/pref_show_current_location"

    android:title="@string/show_current_location"

    android:summary="@string/using_gps_network" 

    android:defaultValue="true"/>

<CheckBoxPreference

    android:key="@string/pref_display_date"

    android:title="@string/display_date"

    android:defaultValue="true"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now you have retreive this stored checkbox value has follows :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        mTimeFormat = sharedPreference.getBoolean("pref_12_time_format", false);
        mServiceType = sharedPreference.getBoolean(
                "pref_show_current_location", false);
        mDisplayDate = sharedPreference.getBoolean("pref_display_date", false);
```

Comment: actually the problem is that the last radion button is unclickable initially untill you click some other button.After clicking some other radio button,the last radio button becomes clickable.plz tell me how to solve this problem sir

Comment: no probs for that,if u change any value that will automatically recognise. u dont worry, whether that button is disabled or enabled. addPreferencesFromResource() will handle the value

Comment: sir please give some example of using addPreferencesFromResource()

Comment: see this link for your expectations :                                http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html                                                       http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html

Comment: And also check this  http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/