# how to save many radiobutton states

Tags: android, string, radio-button

i have an mcq test from question 1 to 10
each question has 4 options which i get from

```
int radioButtonID = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        View radioButton = rg.findViewById(radioButtonID);
        int rbSate = rg.indexOfChild(radioButton) + 1;//since i dont want first option be be 0
```

each question has an unique integer called id
what I did was made a `String s = id+ "_"+rbState + "."`

then i used split string but somehow it is too complicated is there an easier way?

Comment: Are you trying to store radiobutton states to storage ?

Comment: just for temporary use sir so that when the user completes the test he can view the score based on the right answer

Comment: You can just make an array that stores the option selected, i.e. 1/2/3/4 for each question. When the user go back to see his answers, you fetch the number from the array for that question and set radio button as checked accordingly.

Comment: use sharedpreference ...it will help you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482111/how-to-save-the-state-of-radio-buttons

Comment: You can use sharedPreference to store the values